# Configuring sudo on CentOS with LDAP run by Synology Diskstation

Tags: ldap, sudo, sssd, synology

I am trying to set up a CentOS 8 workstation to authenticate against a LDAP server run by a Synology DiskStation. I have been able to successfully configure SSSD to authenticate users against the server, allowing me to login using my LDAP account. However, I am having trouble getting it to grant sudo privileges. Here's my /etc/sssd/sssd.conf file:

```
[domain/lab.university.edu] 
id_provider = ldap 
auth_provider = ldap 
chpass_provider = ldap 
sudo_provider = ldap 
ldap_uri = ldap://00.000.00.00 
ldap_search_base=dc=lab,dc=university,dc=edu 
ldap_sudo_search_base=dc=lab,dc=university,dc=edu 
ldap_group_search_base=dc=lab,dc=university,dc=edu 
ldap_schema = rfc2307bis 
ldap_auth_disable_tls_never_use_in_production = True 
cache_credentials = false 
use_fully_qualified_names = False 
debug_level = 0x3ff0 

[sssd] 
config_file_version = 2 
services = nss,pam,sudo 
domains = lab.university.edu 
debug_level = 0x3ff0 

[nss] 

[pam] 

[sudo]
```

To make sure all changes have been applied, I have also run:

```
sudo authselect select sssd with-mkhomedir with-sudo && sudo systemctl restart sssd.service && sudo sss_cache -E
```

However, I still cannot seem to grant LDAP accounts sudo privileges. I'm wondering if this might potentially have to do with the LDAP user ID/group ID being numbered differently than local accounts. I'm not the one who set up LDAP, but the person who did so explained it was necessary to get everything working. When I type `id ldap_user`, I get the following:

```
uid=1000002(ldap_user) gid=1000001(users) groups=1000001(users),1000003(sudo),1000000(Directory Operators),2097150(Directory Consumers),1000002(administrators),2097149(Directory Clients)
```

Could it be possible that the sudo group isn't getting recognized as valid due to the weird ID numbers?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the appropriated LDAP schema to the schema database of the synology ldap server 
The files are found in the following directory on Centos8:

```
/usr/share/doc/sudo
```

in that directory there are three files:

```
schema.ActiveDirectory  schema.iPlanet  schema.OpenLDAP
```

you need to copy one of these files to the directory on the synology where the schemas are found as long as the synology uses one of these schemas and not something proprietary

then you would need to convert the sudoers file of each host to ldif and import that to the directory server. for that use the utiliy called `cvtsudoers` on previous versions of centos/redhat is was called sudoers2ldif and it was located alongside the schema files.

also note to according to the configuration synology support RFC 2307 and not 2307Bis not sure if that makes a difference.